# How to use LIKE for case insensitive search of partial terms

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with `id, date, time, user, channel, message` and I'm trying to get records based on a username using:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE user LIKE '%dog%'
```

I have at least one user called `Dogge#2252`, and the query does not return anything. Am I using `LIKE` wrong or how do I fix this issue?

To complicate thing further, using

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE user LIKE '%admin%'
```

does return the `Dogge#2252` user.

Comment: try using ILIKE operator instead of LIKE

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks, that seems to work

Comment: Please show the exact rows returned by that second query, and describe exactly how you are running it and showing the results *(because what you describe should be impossible)*.  The first query correctly doesn't return `Dogge#2252`, because a capital `D` is not equal to a lower case `d`, unless you explicitly state you want to use case-insensitive collation.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM log WHERE user ~* 'dog'`, case insensitive [regexp match](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)

Comment: I don't believe that `LIKE '%admin%'` will find `Dogge#2252`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @OldProgrammer: changing

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE user LIKE '%dog%'
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE user ILIKE '%dog%'
```

worked.